# Error: 'SofwareSerial' does not name a type

Tags: programming, softwareserial

I have trouble compiling this sketch. The error I get is

> 'SoftwareSerial' does not name a type

Any ideas how could I fix it?

```
#include SoftwareSerial.h

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  Serial.println("Ready!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port

  // for HC-05 use 38400 when poerwing with KEY/STATE set to HIGH on power on
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Comment: After doing this, I find that SoftwareSerial has a problem in it. Simply by coding #include "SoftwareSerial.h" and not even doing this: //SoftwareSerial Serial(RX, TX); Without SoftwareSerial, I have no idea where to get the output. It does not seem to want to send it to the Serial monitor. That's because there is no Port to select. So I am still stuck. I still get this error: C:\Users\mikey\Documents\Arduino\libraries\attiny_software_serial-master/SoftwareSerial.h:70:17: error: redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'bool' [-fpermissive] typedef uint8_t bool;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to @geometrikal.

or

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
```

Answer (score 8):

You forgot the quotation marks, try

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h" worked instead of
```

`#include <SoftwareSerial.h>`
ie " " not <>